# Unexpected Call to Method or Property Error with JQuery .select()

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, cleditor

I'm using CLEditor as an RTE and it works perfectly except for in IE 8, the error that is produced is:

```
SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access.
jquery.cleditor.js, line 1027 character 7
SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
jquery.cleditor.js, line 1027 character 7
```

The line to which it is referring is the line `editor.range[0].select();` in the following function:

```
function restoreRange(editor) {
    if (ie && editor.range)
        editor.range[0].select();
}
```

I've had a look around for similar questions but none of them have this kind of context. Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is your configuration ? Going to the plugin website, I get no error in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

I'm too low to comment, so I'll suggest this in the answer block...
Could you post some of your document?  Whenever I see a strange error in IE like this for something that should work, I check to see whether the html document has a doctype specified.

Could the issue be IE8 running in quirks mode?